# Limit of a fractional integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find the limit for  `λ -> 0` of the integral listed below, but *Mathematica* give me only a `ConditionalExpression` of `RootSum`, how can evaluate it?
The results should be `1 + C λ^(0.5)+O(λ)` and I am interested in computing `C`.

```
Defft[x_] := (-1 + x)^4
Limit[Integrate[x^2/(λ Defft[x] + x^2 Dmol), {x, 0.0, 1.0}, 
  Assumptions -> 
   Dmol ∈ Reals && λ ∈ Reals && 
    Dmol > 1.0 && λ > 0], λ -> 0]
```

Comment: A tip: for this particular case, use exact numbers (`0`, `1`) instead of inexact ones (`0.0`, `1.0`).

Comment: You can try using `Normal[]` on a `RootSum[]` object before applying `FullSimplify[]`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can factor `Dmol` out of the integral and take the limit as `λ/Dmol` goes to zero.  This may simplify your life somewhat.  (Also, is the limit really 1 as lambda goes to zero?  It looks like just `1/Dmol` if you simply plug in lambda = 0.)

Comment: If you look carefully at the conditions in your `ConditionalExpression`, they boil down to "the denominator does not vanish in the real interval (0,1)."  This happens to be true so long as `λ` and `Dmol` are both positive.  The trick is getting Mathematica to recognize this;  but if you're willing to brute-force it, my answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do the integral without taking the limit, you get the following:

```
Defft[x_] := (-1 + x)^4
foo = Integrate[x^2/(λ Defft[x] + x^2 Dmol), {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> Dmol ∈ Reals && λ ∈ Reals && Dmol > 1 && λ > 0]
```

[image]

The conditions in the `ConditionalExpression` are saying that none of the roots of the polynomial in the denominator are in the real interval (0,1);  and since this is true for positive `λ` and `Dmol` (the quantity is manifestly positive), we can just extract the first part of our results and take the series.  Note that the "result" part of a `ConditionalExpression` is just its first part:

```
Simplify[Series[ToRadicals[foo[[1]]], {λ, 0, 3}], Assumptions -> Dmol > 0]
```

[image].

So C = -π/2 (assuming you've rescaled things such that `Dmol = 1`.)

As I noted above, I haven't been able to get Mathematica to automatically recognize that none of the `Root` objects of the polynomial are in the range of integration.  A better answer would do this automatically rather than extracting the `RootSum` result by hand.

Comment: I don't understand.
 I obtain a different result:   Limit[ConditionalExpression[
  1/2 (-RootSum[
       Dmol + 2 Dmol #1 + Dmol #1^2 + \[Lambda] #1^4 &, (
        Log[-1 - #1] + 2 Log[-1 - #1] #1 + Log[-1 - #1] #1^2)/(
        Dmol + Dmol #1 + 2 \[Lambda] #1^3) &] + 
     RootSum[Dmol + 2 Dmol #1 + Dmol #1^2 + \[Lambda] #1^4 &, (
       Log[-#1] + 2 Log[-#1] #1 + Log[-#1] #1^2)/(
       Dmol + Dmol #1 + 2 \[Lambda] #1^3) &])

Comment: Here all my code:
Clear["Global`*"]
Defft[x_] := (-1 + x)^4
foo = Limit[
  Integrate[x^2/(\[Lambda] Defft[x] + x^2 Dmol), {x, 0, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> 
    Dmol \[Element] Reals && \[Lambda] \[Element] Reals && 
     Dmol > 1 && \[Lambda] > 0], \[Lambda] -> 0]
Simplify[Series[ToRadicals[foo[[1]]], {\[Lambda], 0, 3}], 
 Assumptions -> Dmol > 0]

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I slightly modified the code in my version to make it work;  see the edited version above.

Comment: I still get a different Conditional expression.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Mathematica 10.0.0 on Mac OS 10.10.  The code still works fine on my version;  I'm not sure what to tell you.  Can you edit your original question to show the `ConditionalExpression` that you get?

Comment: On Mac Os works!
But the slight different version with:
Defft[x_] := 1/4 (-1 + x)^4 (2 + 4 x + 6 x^2 + 3 x^3)^2
not Work!
Saying that the solution of the integral is not a meromorphic function when the mathematica try to perform the series.